# What if the frequencies do not define a probability space?

Tags: probability, fake-proofs, paradoxes

In the frequentist interpretation of probability, we define probability as follows

$$P(x) = \lim_{n_t \to \infty}\frac{n_x}{n_t}$$

Where $n_t$ is the number of trials we preform of a certain experiment, and $n_x$ is the number of times we observe the event $x$ occurring during those experiments.

Let's say we have some experiment $E$ that outputs a random natural number, and we are trying to determine the probability distribution on it. So we decide to preform it an infinite number of times, and collect statistics. The first time (whose result we will call $E_0$), we get $0$. The second time ($E_1$), we get $1$. The third time we get $2$. After preforming all the experiments and collecting statistics, we see that $E_n=n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Now, for any $n$, the probability that result of $E$ is $n$ equals $0$ (i.e. $P(\text{$E$ results in $n$})=0$). This seems to violate [the axioms of probability though](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms)! The total probability is $0$, by the third axiom, which contradicts the second axiom.

So, what happened here? Why doesn't the frequentest probabilities corresponding to $E$ form an axiomatically correct probability distribution?

(If you do not like events with infinite domains, you can also use a finite domain. For example, let's say you have a coin that you flip infinitely many times. You get $1$ heads, then $2$ tails, then $4$ heads, then $8$ tails, etc...)

Comment: If the experiment were hypothetically done on something that actually output from a real distribution on the integers, this outcome would not happen. I'm not sure I understand your issue with the coin flips, in the fair coin case, the probability of getting an outcome that does not average to $50\%$ heads is zero by law of large numbers (if that was your objection).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Note: I never said the second coin is fair. My objection was that its probability distribution didn't obey the probabilistic laws.

Comment: explain how it doesn't (and be careful... what is your sample space for the experiment here?)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen the probability $p$ of landing on heads does not converge to a not-negative real number (or any value) violating the first law.

Comment: The strong law of large numbers guarantees that the proportion of heads will converge to $p$ though (where $p$ is the probability of landing on heads).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen it appears that that requires the assumption of finite variance.

Comment: Indicator variables always have finite variance (and it doesn't actually require finite variance, just integrability)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen what is the variance then?

Comment: (And you weren't careful like I asked. There's a difference between the *mathematical* notion that an infinite sequence of independent events of the same probability on the same sample space have proportion converging to $p$ with probability one, and the *interpretational* notion that what it means for a single event on some sample space to have probability $p$ is that if you repeated the same experiment many times its proportion would converge to $p$.)

Comment: The variance of an indicator variable for an event with probability $p$ is $p(1-p)$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen that's not finite though; it's undefined, since $p$ is undefined.

Comment: But you seem to have glossed over my point that there is no hypothetical idealized probability experiment where this will happen.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen what are the rules for what experiments are and aren't valid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70249/discussion-between-spaceisdarkgreen-and-pyrulez).